# min max out of diff sequential groups in single group

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any way to get min/max out of diff sequential groups present in single group ? I want to get `min/max out of all sequential groups in a group`.

Here is the input data

```
id  dt
1   11-01-22
1   12-01-22
1   13-01-22
1   15-01-22
1   19-01-22
1   20-01-22
1   01-01-22
1   02-01-22
1   03-01-22
1   04-01-22
1   08-01-22
```

expected output

```
Id, min    , max
1, 01-01-22, 04-01-22
1, 08-01-22, 08-01-22
1, 11-01-22, 13-01-22
1, 15-01-22, 15-01-22
1, 19-01-22, 20-01-22
```

Trying with this query

```
select 
    id, dt, 
    case when dt - 1 = lag(dt) over (partition by id order by dt) then 0 else 1 end as mark
  from consecutive
order by dt
```

using this am getting two issues

1. Not able to handle null coming from lag of first date in group ? How to handle records marked with `--`.

   ```
    1   01-01-22    1   --
    1   02-01-22    0
    1   03-01-22    0
    1   04-01-22    0
    1   08-01-22    1  
    1   11-01-22    1--
    1   12-01-22    0
    1   13-01-22    0
    1   15-01-22    1  
    1   19-01-22    1--
    1   20-01-22    0
   ```
2. How to manage If I've more than one Ids in table ?

Please share suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try forming pseudo groups of each set of dates which are in sequence.  Then simply aggregate and take the min and max date for each group.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, CASE WHEN dt - LAG(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt) > 1
                     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS val
    FROM yourTable t
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT t.*, SUM(val) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt) AS grp
    FROM cte t
)

SELECT id, MIN(dt) AS min_dt, MAX(dt) AS max_dt
FROM cte2
GROUP BY id, grp
ORDER BY id, MIN(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution from Tim is perfectly fine but this could be simplified to -

```
[SELECT id, MIN(dt), MAX(dt)
  FROM (SELECT id, dt, dt - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dt) rn
          FROM your_table)
 GROUP BY id, rn
 ORDER BY id, rn][1]
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c83895be96e3e12c5cc77b8e9977577e)